# Create DOM hierarchically

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have a list of keys and values and I intend to create an xml based on this information.

My list return:

```
1 person
2 information
3 name
3 surname
2 address
3 street
3 country
```

And I want to generate an xml:

```
<xml>
    <person>
        <information>
            <name></name>
            <surname></surname>
        </information>
        <address>
            <street></street>
            <country></country>
        </address>
    </person>
</xml>
```

I have a list of elements, while traversing these elements would create the xml document hierarchically. I already have this code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
var xml = document.createElement('xml');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var key = elements[i].getAttribute('data-key');
    var value = elements[i].getAttribute('data-value');

    console.log(key +' -> '+ value);

    // HERE: create new elements appendChild "var xml"
}
```

Comment: There are [*many questions already*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+create+XML+document) on creating XML documents, surely one of those is a duplicate? It's not clear whether you want to create an XML string, or an XML document.

Comment: I did research before posting the question and no results dealing with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to Forty3's answer but a tad more concise and uses and XML document, not an HTML document.

Note that if *document* is an HTML document, then *document.createElement* changes the tagname to lower case, whereas if it's an XML document, the tag case is preserved. Also, in an HTML document it's reliant on support for custom and unknown tagnames, which might not be available, so better to use an XML document.

I've made up a data source, it seems it comes from the document so hopefully it reasonably approximate what you're using. I've put some minimal validation on the level, there should be more validation of the input to ensure it meets some standardised format.

```js
function buildDoc() {

  // Create an XML document to use to create the elements
   var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);

  var data = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
  var root = doc.createElement('xml');
  var parent = root;
  var level = 0;
  var node, tagname;

  for (var i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    dataNode = data[i];
    node = doc.createElement(dataNode.dataset.value);        
    nodeLevel = dataNode.dataset.key;

    // Can only add nodes at level 1 or higher
    if (nodeLevel <= 0) {
      console.log('Level ' + nodeLevel + ' is invalid. Can only create nodes at level 1 or higher');
      return;
    }

    // If node at same level, is sibling of current parent
    // If node at lower level, go back levels and parents to same level
    // Append node, then make node the parent
    if (nodeLevel <= level) {
      while (nodeLevel < level) {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
        --level;
      }
      parent = parent.parentNode.appendChild(node);

    // If node at higher level, is child of current parent
    // Next node might higher again, so set parent to node
    } else if (nodeLevel > level){
      parent = parent.appendChild(node);
      level = nodeLevel;
    }
  }
  // Return the root
  return root;
}


window.onload = function() {
  console.log(buildDoc().outerHTML);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="elements" data-key="1" data-value="Person">1 person</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="2" data-value="information">2 information</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="3" data-value="name">3 name</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="3" data-value="surname">3 surname</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="2" data-value="address">2 address</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="3" data-value="street">3 street</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="3" data-value="country">3 country</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="2" data-value="address">2 address</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="3" data-value="street">3 street</span><br>
  <span class="elements" data-key="3" data-value="country">3 country</span><br>
</div>
```

PS. This probably won't run in IE 10 or lower due to lack of support for *data-** attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is untested and I need to step away. But, this should give you a starting point with comments.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
var xml = document.createElement('xml');
var curElem = xml;
var curDepth = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var key = elements[i].getAttribute('data-key');
    var value = elements[i].getAttribute('data-value');

    console.log(key +' -> '+ value);

    // HERE: create new elements appendChild "var xml"

    // Create the new element
    var elem = document.createElement(value);

    // If we are further down the hierarchy, simply add the child
    if (key > curDepth) { 
        curElem.appendChild(elem);
    } else if (key == curDepth) {
        // We are a sibling of our current containing element
        // so simply add to the parent 
        curElem.parentElement.appendChild(elem);
        curElem = elem;
    } else if (key < curDepth) {
        // We are at some point ABOVE our current element
        // so start walking UP until we reach the level indicated
        // and then add the element to the parent
        while (curDepth >= key) {
            curElem = curElem.parentElement;
            curDepth--;
        }
        curElem.parentElement.appendChild(elem);
    }
    curElem = elem;
    curDepth = key;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was close to the solution, but I tried it and it did not turn out to be 100%. I was able to get what I pretedia with the following:

function insertXML(xml, key, value)
{
 let doc = xml;
 let num = 1;
 do {
  if (key == num) {
   let newelem = document.createElement(value);
   doc.appendChild(newelem);
   break;
  } else {
   num = num + 1;
  }
 } while (doc = doc.lastChild);
}

Thank you @Forty3

Comment: @Giest—if you have an answer, you should post it as an answer and accept it. Note that if you are in an HTML document, then *document.createElement* creates HTML elements, not XML elements. That's important because for HTML documents, the tag names will be converted to lower case but for XML, the case will be preserved. It also relies on support for [*custom HTML elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/), which is not ubiquitous.